# Postgres query for difference between latest and first record of the day

Tags: sql, postgresql, grafana

Postgres data alike this:

```
|   id  |         read_at        | value_1 |
| ------|------------------------|---------|
| 16239 | 2021-11-28 16:13:00+00 |   1509  |
| 16238 | 2021-11-28 16:12:00+00 |   1506  |
| 16237 | 2021-11-28 16:11:00+00 |   1505  |
| 16236 | 2021-11-28 16:10:00+00 |   1501  |
| 16235 | 2021-11-28 16:09:00+00 |   1501  |
| ..... | .......................|   ....  |
| 15266 | 2021-11-28 00:00:00+00 |   1288  |
```

A value is added every minute and increases over time.

I would like to get the current total for the day and have this in a Grafana stat panel. Above it would be: 221 (1509-1288). Latest record minus first record of today.

```sql
SELECT id,read_at,value_1
FROM xyz
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

With this the latest record is given (A).

```sql
SELECT id,read_at,value_1
FROM xyz
WHERE read_at = CURRENT_DATE
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

With this the first record of the day is given (B).

Grafana cannot do math on this (A-B). Single query would be best.

Sadly my database knowledge is low and attempts at building queries have not succeeded, and have taken all afternoon now.

Theoretical ideas to solve this:

- Subtract the min from the max value where time frame is today.
- Using a lag, lag it for the count of records that are recorded today. Subtract lag value from latest value.
- Window function.

What is the best way (performance wise) forward and how would such query be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the cumulative total `last_value - first_value` for each record for the current day using window functions (this is the `t` subquery) and then pick the latest one.

```sql
select current_total, read_at::date as read_at_date 
from
(
  select last_value(value_1) over w - first_value(value_1) over w as current_total,
         read_at 
  from the_table
  where read_at >= current_date and read_at < current_date + 1
  window w as (partition by read_at::date order by read_at)
) as t
order by read_at desc limit 1;
```

However if it is certain that `value_1` only "increases over time" then simple grouping will do and that is by far the best way performance wise:

```sql
select max(value_1) - min(value_1) as current_total, 
       read_at::date as read_at_date 
from the_table
where read_at >= current_date and read_at < current_date + 1
group by read_at::date;
```

Comment: Second one performs very fast! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check if it works.

Since you intend to publish it in Grafana, the query does not impose a period filter.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/3080

```
create table g (id int, read_at timestamp, value_1 int);

insert into g
values
(16239, '2021-11-28 16:13:00+00', 1509),
(16238, '2021-11-28 16:12:00+00', 1506),
(16237, '2021-11-28 16:11:00+00', 1505),
(16236, '2021-11-28 16:10:00+00', 1501),
(16235, '2021-11-28 16:09:00+00', 1501),
(15266, '2021-11-28 00:00:00+00', 1288);

select date(read_at), max(value_1) - min(value_1)
from g
group by date(read_at);
```

Comment: A period filter might be logically redundant in this case but it will improve performance a lot especially if the table is large and there is an index on `read_at`.

Comment: Yep, @Stefanov.sm. A dashboard for `the eternity` does not make sense. For the indexes, I don't see how that would work with this table as per-se. BUT, he might add another computed column and, then, create an index on that.

Comment: Time series or sensor data tables do grow a lot over time. And an index on the time column does make sense in a table like this since the dashboard will probably be only one of its use cases.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm, I partially agree. An index on a `TIME` column would not be of much use here. I think it would be better to `ALTER TABLE <XXX> ADD COLUMN read_at_date DATE AS DATE(read_at)` (the syntax is FOR SURE wrong), and, then, `CREATE INDEX AK_XXX_READ_AT_DATE_VALUE ON the_table(read_at_date, value_1)`

Comment: Added `order by date desc LIMIT 1` to get it working. Thanks.

Comment: @Sat, NO....! Or... yes? This gives you the latest date from the data. Not the CURRENT date from the data. Do you really need just one day as result? If so, which? The latest, or the current?

Comment: A calculated column can be avoided (it's redundant anyway) if you do not cast `read_at` as `date` which would defeat the index but use something like `read_at >= current_date and read_at < current_date + 1`. It is a bit more verbose but still easy to read and efficient.

Comment: @MarcusViniciusPompeu latest should be fine as the system will never have data newer than current moment.

Answer (score 0):

Since you data contains multiple values for 2 distinct times (16:09 and 16:10), this indicates the possibility that min and max values do not always increase in the time interval. Leaving open the possibility of a decrease. So do you want max - min reading or the difference in reading at min/max time. The following get value difference to get difference between the first and latest reading of the day as indicated in the title.

```
with parm(dt) as 
     ( values (date '2021-11-28') )
   , first_read (f_read,f_value) as 
     ( select read_at, value_1 
         from test_tbl
        where read_at at time zone 'UTC'= 
                   ( select min(read_at at time zone 'UTC') 
                            from test_tbl
                            join parm  
                              on ((read_at at time zone 'UTC')::date = dt) 
                        )
     ) 
   , last_read (l_read, l_value) as 
     ( select read_at,value_1 
         from test_tbl
        where read_at at time zone 'UTC'= 
                     ( select max(read_at at time zone 'UTC') 
                            from test_tbl
                            join parm  
                              on ((read_at at time zone 'UTC')::date = dt) 
                        )
     ) 
select l_read, f_read, l_value, f_value, l_value - f_value as "Day Difference"
 from last_read 
 join first_read on true;
```